# Kivy not support all cameras on android

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, android-camera, buildozer

**Software Versions**

- Python: 3
- OS: android
- Kivy: 1.10.1
- Build with buildozer

**Describe the bug**
Kivy can only access to 2 camera on android (\dev\video0, \dev\video1) but device has multiple cameras (result from ls /dev/ | grep "video*") `["b'video0\\nvideo1\\nvideo2\\nvideo32\\nvideo33\\nvideo34\\n'"]`.

I notice this error `ServiceManager: Permission failure: android.permission.SYSTEM_CAMERA from uid=10269 pid=27228` when I want to access the camera with index 2.

It only allows using camera video0 and video1.
Permissions are granted for the app in bulldozer spec `android.permissions = CAMERA`.
I define a button that changes the camera's index to see if I can use multiple cameras in one run of the app, and it worked with 0, 1.
I want to use this app with an external camera, which is impossible in this situation. Can anyone help? I can provide git with code if it is necessary.

Error:

```
08-01 18:47:39.705  1370  4278 I Camera2ClientBase: Closed Camera 1. Client was: org.mathor.objectdetection_yolo (PID 27228, UID 10269)
08-01 18:47:39.705  1370  4278 I Camera3-Device: disconnectImpl: E
08-01 18:47:39.706  1370  2972 W ServiceManager: Permission failure: android.permission.SYSTEM_CAMERA from uid=10269 pid=27228
08-01 18:47:39.707 27228 27292 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
08-01 18:47:39.707 27228 27292 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
08-01 18:47:39.707 27228 27292 I python  :    File "/Users/matho/MyRepo/Repository/KivyApps/object_detection/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 25, in <module>
08-01 18:47:39.708 27228 27292 I python  :    File "/Users/matho/MyRepo/Repository/KivyApps/object_detection/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/objectdetection_yolo/armeabi-v7a/kivy/app.py", line 955, in run
08-01 18:47:39.708 27228 27292 I python  :    File "/Users/matho/MyRepo/Repository/KivyApps/object_detection/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/objectdetection_yolo/armeabi-v7a/kivy/base.py", line 574, in runTouchApp
08-01 18:47:39.708 27228 27292 I python  :    File "/Users/matho/MyRepo/Repository/KivyApps/object_detection/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/objectdetection_yolo/armeabi-v7a/kivy/base.py", line 339, in mainloop
08-01 18:47:39.709 27228 27292 I python  :    File "/Users/matho/MyRepo/Repository/KivyApps/object_detection/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/objectdetection_yolo/armeabi-v7a/kivy/base.py", line 383, in idle
08-01 18:47:39.709 27228 27292 I python  :    File "/Users/matho/MyRepo/Repository/KivyApps/object_detection/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/objectdetection_yolo/armeabi-v7a/kivy/base.py", line 334, in dispatch_input
08-01 18:47:39.709 27228 27292 I python  :    File "/Users/matho/MyRepo/Repository/KivyApps/object_detection/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/objectdetection_yolo/armeabi-v7a/kivy/base.py", line 263, in post_dispatch_input
08-01 18:47:39.709 27228 27292 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
08-01 18:47:39.709 27228 27292 I python  :    File "/Users/matho/MyRepo/Repository/KivyApps/object_detection/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/objectdetection_yolo/armeabi-v7a/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1660, in on_motion
08-01 18:47:39.709 27228 27292 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
08-01 18:47:39.709 27228 27292 I python  :    File "/Users/matho/MyRepo/Repository/KivyApps/object_detection/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/objectdetection_yolo/armeabi-v7a/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1677, in on_touch_down
08-01 18:47:39.709 27228 27292 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
08-01 18:47:39.709 27228 27292 I python  :    File "/Users/matho/MyRepo/Repository/KivyApps/object_detection/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/objectdetection_yolo/armeabi-v7a/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 589, in on_touch_down
08-01 18:47:39.710 27228 27292 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
08-01 18:47:39.710 27228 27292 I python  :    File "/Users/matho/MyRepo/Repository/KivyApps/object_detection/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/objectdetection_yolo/armeabi-v7a/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 589, in on_touch_down
08-01 18:47:39.710 27228 27292 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
08-01 18:47:39.710 27228 27292 I python  :    File "/Users/matho/MyRepo/Repository/KivyApps/object_detection/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/objectdetection_yolo/armeabi-v7a/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
08-01 18:47:39.711 27228 27292 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 727, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
08-01 18:47:39.711 27228 27292 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1307, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
08-01 18:47:39.711 27228 27292 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1231, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
08-01 18:47:39.711 27228 27292 I python  :    File "/Users/matho/MyRepo/Repository/KivyApps/object_detection/.buildozer/android/app/custom_camera/custom_camera.py", line 35, in change_index
08-01 18:47:39.711 27228 27292 I python  :    File "/Users/matho/MyRepo/Repository/KivyApps/object_detection/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/objectdetection_yolo/armeabi-v7a/kivy/core/camera/__init__.py", line 90, in _set_index
08-01 18:47:39.711 27228 27292 I python  :    File "/Users/matho/MyRepo/Repository/KivyApps/object_detection/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/objectdetection_yolo/armeabi-v7a/kivy/core/camera/camera_android.py", line 49, in init_camera
08-01 18:47:39.711 27228 27292 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 1177, in jnius.jnius.JavaMultipleMethod.__call__
08-01 18:47:39.712 27228 27292 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 884, in jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.__call__
08-01 18:47:39.712 27228 27292 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 1056, in jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.call_staticmethod
08-01 18:47:39.712 27228 27292 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_utils.pxi", line 91, in jnius.jnius.check_exception
08-01 18:47:39.712 27228 27292 I python  :  jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: Unknown camera ID java.lang.RuntimeException
08-01 18:47:39.712 27228 27292 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Buildozer.spec

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = ObjectDetection

# (str) Package name
package.name = objectdetection_yolo

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.mathor

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,opencv,numpy,Pillow

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.10.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = CAMERA

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
android.accept_sdk_license = True

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
bin_dir = ../bin
```

Main code

```
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, NumericProperty, StringProperty
from image_processing.image_processing import face_detection, people_detection, car_detection
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import kivy
import numpy as np
import cv2
import subprocess

from android.permissions import request_permission, Permission, check_permission

class CustomCamera(Camera):
    detect_name = StringProperty("Face Detection")
    info_text = StringProperty("")
    detect_func = NumericProperty(0)
    angle = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.isAndroid = kivy.platform == "android"
        if self.isAndroid:
            self.angle = -90

    def change_index(self, *args):
        # python  : ["b'video0\\nvideo1\\nvideo2\\nvideo32\\nvideo33\\nvideo34\\n'"]
        cameras = str(self.list_cameras())
        print(cameras)
        if self.index == 0:
            new_index = 1
        elif self.index == 1:
            new_index = 32
        else:
            new_index = 0
        self._camera._set_index(new_index)
        self.index = new_index
        self.info_text = str(cameras)
        self.angle = -90 if self.index == 0 else 90

    def list_cameras(self):
        p = subprocess.Popen('ls /dev/ | grep "video*"', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        return str(p.communicate()[0]).split('\\n')


    def on_tex(self, *l):
        image = np.frombuffer(self._camera._texture.pixels, dtype='uint8')
        w,h = self._camera._texture.size
        image = image.reshape(h, w, -1)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGR)

        if self.detect_func == 1: 
            image, faceRect = face_detection(image, (0, 255, 0, 255), self.angle)
        elif self.detect_func == 2:
            image, bodies = people_detection(image, (0, 255, 0, 255), self.angle)
        elif self.detect_func == 3:
            image, cars = car_detection(image, (0, 255, 0, 255), self.angle)

        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        numpy_data = image.tostring()

        self._camera._texture.blit_buffer(numpy_data, bufferfmt="ubyte", colorfmt='rgba')
        super(CustomCamera, self).on_tex(self._camera)


    def get_cameras_count(self):
        cameras = 1
        if self.isAndroid:
            cameras = self._camera.get_camera_count()
        return cameras

    def toggle_camera(self):
        if not check_permission(Permission.CAMERA):
            request_permission(Permission.CAMERA)
        else:
            self.play = not self.play

    def detect(self):
        self.detect_func = self.detect_func + 1 if self.detect_func != 3 else 0
        if self.detect_func == 0:
            self.detect_name = 'Face Detection'
        elif self.detect_func == 1:
            self.detect_name = "People Detection"
        elif self.detect_func == 2:
            self.detect_name = "Car Detection"
        elif self.detect_func == 3:
            self.detect_name = "Turn off"


class CameraWidget(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CameraWidget, self).__init__(orientation="vertical")
        if self.ids['camera'].get_cameras_count() > 1:
            self.ids['buttons'].add_widget(Button(text="Change Camera", on_press=self.ids['camera'].change_index))
```

Comment: Reminder that Android != Linux. From what I can tell `kivy.uix.camera` is using Android APIs: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/core/camera/camera_android.py so if the Android framework doesn't expose more than 2 cameras, there are only 2 cameras. Also `I want to use this app with an external camera` implies that you want to use a external USB camera, however Android has no requirement to support USB camera and on consumer phone hardware the app would need its own driver code. Of course if you are trying to run on speciality hardware check with the OEM.